Express Body Parser Too Much Large Payload
Why it's still says payload is too large??
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "1024mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "1024mb" }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1024mb" }));

Note: I'm using Quill Rich Editor and uploading images.
I'm trying to create a post with that.

I was did that..
